# How to put accents and "ç"?

Tags: template10

When using Template 10, when I try to use words with accents or "ç" appears some strange characters. I've tried looking for some definition but found nothing. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Template Override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages.aspx), which allows you to override the standard setting and set it to anything you want, UTF-8 should help.

Comment: how and where to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1º) Open the XAML file

2º) Go to File > Save As...

3º) Click on the down arrow at the Save button  and select "Save with Encoding..."

4º) Select the Unicode (UTF-8 with Signature) Codepage 65001

5º) Do this to all your xaml files